# Tooltip prevents clicking "Add" button

Tags: w2ui

Thanks for providing this great plugin.

I am using version 1.5 (master branch).  When I place the mouse to click on the "Add" button, the tooltip shows up and prevent me from clicking on it.  I have the same code I used with version 1.4, and only updated to the master branch.

Here is a recording of what happens: http://g.recordit.co/LKo1dGpmEs.gif

Do I have to setup the grid differently or is this a know bug?

Comment: The tooltip is supposed to appear above the button. Maybe you've got some CSS that's interfering with the item? Maybe you forgot to update the CSS file from 1.4 to 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mpf82, I went back and isolated the CSS line which was conflicting.  I am using the `foundation` library, and it has a line for the `body` tag which sets `position: relative;`  This was causing w2ui to misplace the tooltip.  I added the following line to reset the `position` to the initial setting, and that worked fine.

```
body {
  position: initial;
}
```